# Sound gone after recent update to 21.10

Tags: kde, 21.10, ubuntu-studio

I have a Lenovo X395, running UbuntuStudio 21.10. I applied some updates over the weekend and, since then, my sound no longer works. :-(

I have a "No output or input devices found" message when I try to access the KDE sound/volume controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Chris

Comment: Did you ever get it working?